# What is ~/default used for?

Tags: directory

When I connect to my server using a the shell provided by [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) it executes ~/default before every command. I can't find out if this is Capistrano related or if this file has some generic use like `~/.bash_profile` for instance. I use Ubuntu 12.04.

If I create `~/default` containing `echo "wut?"` and connect to that server using `cap shell` (Capistrano shell, a non-login, non-interative shell ..) it will echo "wut?" before every command that I execute in that shell session.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make things clearer

Comment: There's no convention regarding a file called `default`. It's just some name your colleague used.

Comment: This question is unanswerable because it is about a naming choice made by one person.

Comment: It's not about the naming choice by one person at all, I can't believe how much you can miss the point.. but I'm perfectly happy for it to be closed if the file is Capistrano specific, rather than a system file as I thought.

Comment: [Here is a diagram of the files loaded](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/#which_startup_files_loaded)  by the cap shell and they do not include `~/default`, so there is some other explanation (e.g., you've referenced it from one of those).

Comment: As Gilles has mentioned `default` is not a standard unix file, and golidilocks' reference show this too, so we can only guess that it must be related to something else. Stack overflow has a [tagged section for Capstrano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capistrano) which might be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks and X Tian, I already asked the person who maintains Capistrano and he didn't know. It's also not referenced in any of my shell startup files. I guess I'll consign this one to the category of "i'll never know" and move on.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/
```

Is in fact an alias for your home directory  and equal

```
cd /home/YourUsername
```

In the case of `nginx` the home folder is probably `/var/www` or something similar you can find out in looking into `/etc/passwd` and looking for the `ngnix` user

You can for example when you're `root` authenticate as any user.

```
sudo user_that_launch_your_daemon  
#or 
su user_that_launch_your_daemon
file ~/default
```

and you'll know what it is either a file or a folder.

Comment: I think you can use the commands `echo $HOME` or `ls -d ~` to find the home directory of a user, you don't have to use `/etc/passwd`...

Comment: Or just `~nginx` or `~www-data` or `~username`.

Comment: I'm interested in what the file `default` is, sorry, my question can't have been clear enough.

Comment: @MikeCampbell you should **[edit]** your question to make it more explicit. in this case default is eitheir a folder or a file located in the home directory of your daemon

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`~/default` is the files location, where `~` is the home directory of that user - so the file should be called `default` in the users home directory. You can use this command

```
echo $HOME
```

or this one:

```
ls -d ~
```

to find the home directory of a user, you don't have to use `/etc/passwd`. You would have to run the command as that user, you can find out which user you are using if needs be by running `whoami`

So the file needs to be located at the result of this command

```
echo $(ls -d ~)/default
```

or this command:

```
echo $HOME/default
```

Comment: There may be a chance of `~/default` would be a directory name.

Comment: My question was precisely about the purpose of the specific file named `default` in the users' home directory.